# Using IF and Subquery

Tags: mysql, if-statement, count, subquery

I am a beginner in SQL. I have a table of attendance like this:

**ID--EID ---- PunchIn --------------------POut**
1---101-----'2012-05-01 07:30:00'-----'2012-05-01 10:00:00'
2---101-----'2012-05-01 13:30:00'-----'2012-05-01 19:00:00'
3---102-----'2012-05-01 07:45:00'-----'2012-05-01 17:30:00'
4---103-----'2012-05-01 08:00:00'-----'2012-05-01 18:30:00'

How do I write a query that will produce anything like this:

**ID--EID ---- PunchIn --------------------POut**
1---101-----**'2012-05-01 07:30:00'-----'2012-05-01 19:00:00'**
3---102-----'2012-05-01 07:45:00'-----'2012-05-01 17:30:00'
4---103-----'2012-05-01 08:00:00'-----'2012-05-01 18:30:00'

thank you

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? It's easy to find queries that work for your specific example, but it's hard to guess what you want for the general case.

Comment: Everything Mark says plus - why do you think you need and 'if' and a 'subquery'

Comment: -1 because I already told you your question doesn't state what you are trying to do. Instead of spending time making your question more clear you just say that the answers don't do what *still* without saying what it is you are trying to do. Fix your question first, then you will get good answers. We are not psychics. Explain the problem, show what you've tried, show what fails, show what you want to happen, give examples to show how edge cases should be handled. Make your question **clear** and **unambiguous**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure, but if you just want to collapse all punches regarding the same date and the same person, you could just use a group by, therefore, if the table name is PUNCHES:

```
SELECT ID, EID, MIN(PunchIn), MAX(POut)
FROM PUNCHES
GROUP BY ID, DATE(PunchIn);
```

Comment: Wrong, if anything it is `GROUP BY EID`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, EID, MIN( PunchIn ) , MAX( POut )
FROM PUNCHES
GROUP BY EID
```

You can try this one.